# Rspec controller test assign two dimensional Hash fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, rspec, controller

i'm trying to run a controller test:
the controller code is

```
def aix_service_accounts
  @no_dn_users= Hash.new
  record = 0
  @no_dn_users[record]= Hash.new
  @no_dn_users[record]['aix_username'] ="abc"
end
```

The rspec code is

```
  it "should show aix_service_accounts" do
    get :aix_service_accounts
    expect(assigns(:no_dn_users[0]['aix_username'])).to eq 'abc'
  end
```

The result is

> Failures:

1) AixController should show aix_service_accounts
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:no_dn_users[0]['aix_username'])).to eq 'abc'

```
   expected: "abc"
        got: {"marked_for_same_origin_verification"=>true, "no_dn_users"=>{0=>{"aix_username"=>"abc"}}}

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
   -"abc"
   +"marked_for_same_origin_verification" => true,
   +"no_dn_users" => {0=>{"aix_username"=>"abc"}},

 # ./spec/controllers/aix_controller_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Could anyone help and explain the reason to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - you're trying to ask for a single key called `:no_dn_users[0]['aix_username']` from the assigns. You need to change that to:

```
assigns(:no_dn_users)[0]['aix_username']
```

instead.

Ie, get out the first part by the key `:no_dn_users`, this will be the hash-inside-an-array that you're then referencing using indexing